# SQL Server - Concatenate all child IDs into delimited string in parent record

Tags: sql-server

I've a question about a hierarchical (adjacency model) SQL Server table. This link [Get child records on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446424/get-child-records-on-one-column) shows how to populate a parent field with a concatenated list of all child records. So the "Children" column in my table becomes:

```
ID ParentID Name   Children
1  NULL     Root   2,3
2  1        L2-1   4
3  1        L2-3   NULL
4  2        L3-4   6
5  3        L3-5   NULL
6  4        L4-6   NULL
```

Could someone advise how I could do this for multiple levels i.e. all descendants, not just the immediate children?

i.e. I'd like the table to be:

```
ID ParentID Name   Children
1  NULL     Root   2,3,4,5,6
2  1        L2-1   4,6
3  1        L2-3   5
4  2        L3-4   6
5  3        L3-5   NULL
6  4        L4-6   NULL
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the query below. I assumed your table name is Children.

It first builds a list of parents up to the top (first query). Then it puts all separate branches together (second query).

```
WITH temp (ID, ParentID, ChildrenChain)
AS
(
    SELECT ID, ParentID, CAST('' AS VARCHAR(100))
    FROM children
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM children cc WHERE cc.ParentID = children.ID)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT children.ID, children.ParentID, CAST((temp.ChildrenChain + ',' + CAST(temp.ID AS VARCHAR(100))) AS VARCHAR(100)) 
    FROM children
    INNER JOIN temp ON children.ID = temp.ParentID
)

SELECT DISTINCT ID,
    REPLACE(
        STUFF(
           (SELECT
                ',' + t2.ChildrenChain
                FROM temp t2
                WHERE temp.ID=t2.ID
                ORDER BY t2.ChildrenChain
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
           ).value('.','varchar(max)')
           ,1,2, ''
        ), 
    ',,', ',') AS ChildValues
FROM temp
WHERE LEN(ChildrenChain) > 0
```

Let me know if that doesn't work for you.